# Validation to prevent duplicated values on input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Im trying to prevent duplicated values on inputs with same name when I click a submit button, but it is not working and i am not sure why...
I need some help to understand why is not working? 
Thanks  lot in advance!

this is my code:

I tried with a solution I found here which it worked "on input change" behavior, but it doesnt with button click... 
My button:

```
<button type="button" id="approve" class="positive valid" tabindex="-1">Approve</button>
```

and my jquery

```
$('#received').on('click',function() {
    var $current = $(this);
    if ($('input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]').val() == $current.val() && $('input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]').attr('tabindex') !== $current.attr('tabindex') ) {
    alert('You can not have duplicated ID´s');
       return false;                        
    }else {
       return true;
    }
});
```

I want to show an alert and prevent the submit.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: post the HTML please

Comment: What's the value of `#received`? What are the values in the `RE_SignedByID` elements? It would help to see your HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The values in RE_SignedBy are "id numbers" like "987812-1324" the #received is a button <button class="positive" id="received"> Received </button>

Comment: In that case what is the purpose of checking the value of the button? Are you only intending to stop duplicate values in the `RE_SignedBy` fields?

Comment: Ahh that is what im doing wrong! I shoud check the values before the "on click" action? Yes onlöy want to stop duplicated values

Comment: You checking the name or number is same or not

Comment: #received is a submit button?

Comment: @Tom Yes #recived is a submit, Im trying to check that tree input text with same 'name=" " ' dont have duplicated values (in this case an ID number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're comparing the value of the clicked button to the first `input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]` element.

To fix this you could instead create an array of all the `input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]` values using `map()`. You can then dedupe this list and compare the resulting array lengths. If they are different there was a duplicate. Try this:

```js
$('#received').on('click', function(e) {
  var values = $('input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]').map(function() {
    return this.value.trim();
  }).get();  
  var unique =  [...new Set(values)];

  if (values.length != unique.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('You can not have duplicated ID\'s');
  }
});
```

Note that `[...new Set(values)]` will not work in IE. If you need to support legacy browsers there are plenty of alternatives to dedupe an array. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/519413) for more information.

Comment: I see! To get the values on an Array would be the soution I think, Im doing the checking of the values wrong, Im realizing that now... I'll make some changes

Comment: can I have unique like this? var unique =  $('input[name^="RE_SignedByID"]').val();

Comment: No, as calling `val()` on a collection of elements will only read the first. This is why I suggested using `map()` to read the values from *all* the elements in to a single array

Comment: Allright :) Im trying to replace [...new Set(values)] cause it will be a problem if it does not work on IE. Thanks Rory!

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it! Here is the code... you can add a button event like:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () { 


 var values = $('[name=RE_SignedByID]').map(function() {
                return this.value.trim();
                }).get(); 

                var values2= $('[name=RE_OwnersID]').map(function() {
                return this.value.trim();
                }).get(); 
                values.sort();
                values2.sort();
                for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) { 
                if( values[i] == values[i+1] && values[i] !=""){

                showAlert(translator.getTranslation(' You can not have duplicated signers ID\'s'));
                return false;
              //  break;
                }
                } 
                for (var i = 0; i < values2.length-1; i++) { 
                if( values2[i] == values2[i+1] && values2[i] !=""){

                showAlert(translator.getTranslation(' You can not have duplicated owners ID\'s'));
                return false;
              //  break;
                }
                }
 });
```